# Create complex fileset conditions in Nant

Tags: nant

I wand to deploy my site by hand (just copy required files) via Nant. But I need couple of `.cs` files in `App_Code` directory. I prepared following code, but it is excluding all `.cs` files and do not include files in `App_Code`. What is precedence (if exists) of `include`/`exclude`? How to fix it?

```
<copy todir="${deploy.dir}">
  <fileset basedir="D:\Src\MyRroj\Web">
    <include name="**/*"/>
    <exclude name="**/*.cs"/>
    <include name="App_Code/*.cs"/>
    <exclude name="Web.config.template"/>
    <exclude name="SqlMap.config.template"/>
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

Answer (score 1):

Include adds files and exclude trims files.  Ordering includes,excludes shouldn't matter as the includes are applied first and then excludes are applied.  Normally I would suggest making 2 `filesets`, but `copy` doesn't support multiple `filesets`, so the easiest solution is 2 separate copy commands.

```
<copy todir="${deploy.dir}">
  <fileset basedir="D:\Src\MyRroj\Web">
    <include name="**/*"/>
    <exclude name="**/*.cs"/>
    <exclude name="Web.config.template"/>
    <exclude name="SqlMap.config.template"/>
  </fileset>
</copy>
<copy todir="${deploy.dir}">
  <fileset basedir="D:\Src\MyRroj\Web">
    <include name="App_Code/*.cs"/>
  </fileset>
</copy>
```